# Disk became RAW after chkdsk operation

Tags: hard-drive, chkdsk, diskpart, raw

After chkdsk detected a wrong index entry and acted, a disk became RAW.

1. With diskpart, trying to clean it before formatting yields:

   ```
   DISKPART> clean
   DiskPart has encountered an error: The device is not ready.
   See the System Event Log for more information.
   ```
2. Could not find any corresponding entry in Event Log > System
3. Then tried:

   ```
   DISKPART> detail disk

   ST8000DM 004-2CX188 USB Device
   Disk ID: {500ACEB6-CDF0-47C2-882D-1905B6CD8F1C}
   Type   : USB
   Status : Online
   Path   : 0
   Target : 0
   LUN ID : 0
   Location Path : UNAVAILABLE
   Current Read-only State : No
   Read-only  : No
   Boot Disk  : No
   Pagefile Disk  : No
   Hibernation File Disk  : No
   Crashdump Disk  : No
   Clustered Disk  : No

     Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
     ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
     Volume 10                     RAW    Partition   7452 GB  Healthy
   ```
4. Given the result, it seems that the disk is alive.

Is there anything that could be done?

Comment: A disk shouldn't become RAW just because an index entry was fixed. Evidently, your disk has encountered a catastrophic error. Does Disk Manager show the disk? Can you right-click it and select Initialize?

Comment: You can examine partition TAB in DMDE, https://superuser.com/a/1782757/705502. It's wise to clone the drive using something like ddrescue.

Comment: You might be able to recover the partition table with TestDisk but it’s not guaranteed

Comment: @harrymc
Disk Manager shows it.
It's possible to assign a drive letter.
Format fails.

Comment: @Joep van Steen Trying to select it with DMDE the app says "The disk is not accessible".

Comment: @Ramhound TestDisk is unable to find a partition (used to be GPT).

Comment: It seems that - as stated by @harrymc - it was just a coincidence: disk already had a problem which chkdsk tried to correct but shortly afterwards it failed, even though its presence is still detectable.
Knowing about DMDE and TestDisk was worth it.
Wish to thank all three of you for your time.
K

Comment: @pstrg - You are out of luck in that case. Essentially if you have been trying to format the partition with your data.

Comment: @pstrg, it suggests a problem with the drive itself. time to check SMART.